# How to AutoRotate only MPMoviePlayerController in a ViewController?

Tags: rotation, mpmovieplayercontroller, autorotate, mpmovieplayer

I have tried many solutions but not worked yet! I'm developing iOS 6.1 iPhone app on Xcode 4.6.3.

I am using an MPMoviePlayerController in my application. I have 4 tabbed application. Movieplayer is in SecondViewController. I am not presenting it as a view controller but adding its view to my own view controller. The video plays just fine and I can go fullscreen.

Here's my code below. Any solutions?

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

@synthesize moviePlayer;

- (IBAction)playVideo:(id)sender {

    NSURL * url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://server:1935/live/test/playlist.m3u8"];

    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];

    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];

    moviePlayer.fullscreen = YES;
    moviePlayer.allowsAirPlay = YES;

    }

@end
```

Comment: What have you tried and why did that not work for you as expected? What **exactly** are you expecting. Should the wrapping tab-controller  rotate in embedded mode or do you expect the player to autorotate only in fullscreen mode,....?

Comment: I'm building an app in portrait orientation. But i want to autorotate the player when a video is played in fullscreen mode.